# Добавить перед точкой свой текст в предложении PHP

Tags: php

У меня есть строка, например, "001.jpg". Как перед точкой добавить нужное мне слово. Чтобы получить, "001hello.jpg" ?

Answer (score 2):

Например, так:

```php
$string = '001.jpg';
$parts = explode('.', $string);
echo $parts[0] . 'hello.' . $parts[1];
```

Если в строке может быть несколько символов `.`:

```php
$string = '001.002.003.jpg';
$parts = explode('.', $string);

$result = [];
for ($i = 0; $i < count($parts); $i++) {
    $result[] = ($i == count($parts) - 2) ? $parts[$i] . 'hello' : $parts[$i];
}
echo implode('.', $result);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$str = "001.jpg";
$add = "hello";

echo str_replace('.', $add . '.', $str);
```

---

```
$string = '001.jpg';
$add = "hello";
$pattern = '/(.*?)(\.)(.*?)/i';
$replacement = '${1}' . $add .  '${2}${3}';
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
```

Answer (score 1):

Один из вариантов оказался вот такой пример:

```html
$t = 001.jpg;
$t = str_replace(
["."], //
["hello."],
$t
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Ещё вариант в коллекцию ответов

```
$str = '001.jpg';
$add = 'hello';

$pos = strpos($str, '.');
$str = substr($str, 0, $pos) . $add . substr($str, $pos);

echo $str;
```